# How to get filtered target device information from windows upper class filter

Tags: driver, kmdf, wpd, wdf

I'm writing a upper class filter for WPD device. I specified the callback functions for the Read/Write/Ioctl, from the callback declaration I could get the WDFQueue, WDFRequest.

```
VOID WdfFltrDeviceControl(IN WDFQUEUE Queue, IN WDFREQUEST Request, IN size_t OutputBufferLength, IN size_t InputBufferLength, IN ULONG IoControlCode)
```

But from the parameter Queue or Request, I could only get the information of device which is created by my driver. Is there any way to retrieve the informations of the attached devices which my driver is currently filtering?(e.g. From the kernel log I can see the ioctl request to my android device, but I don't know how to get the android device object to get the device name)

Answer (score 0):

You are really should be able to get information about your WPD device request using parameters of this method. If you are not, probably your code or .inf filter setup is wrong.

You can use this code snippet to check what device you are filtering now:

```
WDFDEVICE device = WdfIoQueueGetDevice(Queue);
WCHAR id[255];
ULONG resultLength;
NTSTATUS status = WdfDeviceQueryProperty(device, DevicePropertyHardwareID, sizeof(id), id, &resultLength);
if(NT_SUCCESS(status))
{
//check the device id here
}
```

Or, if you prefer some another parameter, you could find the list [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/wdm/ne-wdm-device_registry_property)